# Heroku: How to update column name in heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Although my app works in my cloud development environment (colud9), `We're sorry, but something went wrong.` is displayed when I access heroku's url.

I changed column's name in my development environment.

I tried the followings commands;

```
git commit -a -m "xxx"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

When I check the `schema` in heroku, column's name haven't been changed.

How can I update column's name in my heroku app?

It could be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: did you add the migration file before commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that, you have not added the migration file before creating commit. so you need to add the migration file and then need to create commit. Please follow the following commands.

1) Add Migration files to Git git add .

2) Commit git commit -m "Adding migration file"

3) Push the changes to Heroku git push heroku master - assuming you are using 
heroku as your remote name and you are working in the master branch

4)run heroku run rake db:migrate to run the migrations ON HEROKU

5)Following migrations do heroku restar

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is launch a console on heroku:

```
heroku run console
```

For e.g you want to update column name for `users` table
Then do the following:

```
User.all.each {|user| user.update_attribute :column_name}
```

In case you want to give some default value to your column, than do the following:

`User.all.each {|user| user.update_attribute :column_name, 'value'}`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

run `heroku run rake db:version` check if the version matches your last migration in your local machine. if not follow @power suggestion.